# Combing two digital sound files

Tags: audio, voice, levels

Why Combing two digital sound files into one digital sound file often involves adjustment of dB level
?

Mathematically, a 5.1 sound file is much larger than a stereo sound file. why?

Answer (score 0):

When two signals are summed on a normalized scale of 0 to 1 as it usually is in the blocks in memory, often directly summing them will make for an increase in overall sound level that does not fit in with the logarithmic decibel scale. In addition, the levels need to be corrected to select the relative levels of the two signals. They need to be corrected before they are summed so they are not too loud, and so that they are the correct relative volume.

To answer your other question, a 5.1 file typically has 6 channels of audio going on at one given time. A stereo sound file only has two channels at most. So the 5.1 equivalent of a soundfile (metadata excluded) would be usually right around three times larger than your average stereo file of an equivalent bitrate.